# Stop OnLongClickListener while dragging

Tags: android, android-view

I made my View, you can put other views in it.

This parent View can be dragged (dispatchTouchEvent).

But when I drag the parent View, the views that are contained in it are called onLongClick.

If you block ACTION_DOWN, the screen is not clickable, I need it to be clickable.

How to fix?

I made View in a separate library and so old solutions will not help.

Comment: `dispatchTouchEvent` why are u overriding this ?

Comment: Recycler View in views blocks onTouchEvent

Comment: then simple set your parent. requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent= true/false on Action_DOWN and Action_UP

Comment: Read about how event's work in android and explore more

Comment: requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent sttill won't cancel onLongClick...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to solve this problem.
view.cancelPendingInputEvents();

Answer (score 0):

Just create a boolean flag `isDragging` and when ACTION_MOVE is triggered then set the flag to `true` and in `onLongClick` method have a check if isDragging is false then only allow longPress.And ACTION_UP reset the flag i.e. `isDragging = false`

> NOTE: set the isDragging flag only if the touch is not sloppy. to check the sloppy touch have some threshold diffX and diffY values.if the move event is above those threshold's then only set the `isDragging`

```
override fun onLongClick(v: View): Boolean {
if(v is YourView){
    if(!v.isDragging){
        val message = messages[adapterPosition]
            listener?.onLongClickMessage(message)
            setColorMessage(message, background)
            return true
            }
        }
        return false
}
```

Comment: And how to cancel the vibration?

Comment: share ur on longClick code and whole touch listener code. i will be able to help you is better way

Comment: https://pastebin.com/figVimxX this is touch listener.
https://pastebin.com/M7eTBdJg onLongClick

Comment: OnLongClick in ViewHolder is in the adapter. On touch listener in another module.

Comment: you will have to decide when to activate `isDragging` according to your business logic. and keep the getter of `isDragging` as public so that is can be used from anywhere.

Comment: You did not understand. I put Views in my custom View. I cannot create a flag in Views

Comment: onTouchEvent in parent View. onLongClick in children views